# FIrebase 401 unauthorized error FCM in Android

Tags: php, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Firstly we create FCM project and get on googlePlayService.json file and if we send notification by using FCM console then Notification send successfully in our android app But if we send notification through local server then 401 unauthorized error comes so please suggest me can we change code in php server or android.

Comment: If you get a 401 unauthorized  error. Maybe your API Key in your local server is wrong. See [This Google documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#interpret-downstream). Check your API key in your PHP server implementation.

Comment: Check maybe you're sending outside the specified IP addresses in your restrictions.

Comment: No !  how to get Server Key Through FCM because when i Search my server key in my FCM dashboard there is no server key please help me.

Comment: When you need to retrieve the current app registration token, call FirebaseInstanceID.getToken(). Refer FCM docs here - https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/first-message

Answer (score 10):

To get Firebase Cloud Messaging's Server Key, please goto your Firebase Console and see the following screen shot to get your "Server Key" value.

[image]